# How to import re and formatting code

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import re and have a format for a license plate in my original code, however I have the code but just do not know where to put it. I hope this is clear in my coding.

```
import re
    number_plate = re.match('\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}','12MNB36'):
```

The above code is what i am trying to input into my actual code shown below.

```
over_limit = []
file=open("newfile.txt", "w")

while True:
    speed = float()
    distance = 10
    time =float(raw_input('enter time'))
    speed = distance/time
    number_plate = raw_input('enter number plate')
    print speed


if speed>31.2928:
    #70 mph converted into m/s
    over_limit.append(number_plate)
    print over_limit
    file.write(number_plate)


else:
    print 'ok'
file.close()
```

Comment: You have the wrong number of letters and numbers in your regex. It should be 2 numbers, 3 letters, 2 numbers. `number_plate = re.search('\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}','12MNB36')`

Comment: My task is to do it as shown above in the format 2 letters, two numbers, three letters.

Comment: Well then you provided a bad example license plate, because that does not match your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might write what it looks like you're trying to do:

```
import re

PLATE_PATTERN = r'\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}'

with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:
    over_limit = []
    while True:
        distance = 10
        print
        time  = raw_input('Enter time: ')
        if time.lower() == 'x':
            print("Goodbye.")
            break
        speed = distance / float(time)
        print("Speed: %s" % speed)

        if speed>31.2928:
            #70 mph converted into m/s
            print('Over Limit!')
            while True:
                number_plate = raw_input('Enter number plate: ')
                if re.match(PLATE_PATTERN, number_plate):
                    over_limit.append(number_plate)
                    f.write(number_plate)
                    print("Plate Recorded.")
                    break
                else:
                    print("error: '%s' didn't match regex '%s'" % (number_plate, PLATE_PATTERN))

        else:
            print('Speed OK')
```

In action:

```
Enter time: 1
Speed: 10.0
Speed OK

Enter time: .2
Speed: 50.0
Over Limit!
Enter number plate: ABC123
error: 'ABC123' didn't match regex '\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}'
Enter number plate: 12AB345
Plate Recorded.

Enter time: x
Goodbye.
```

There's a lot of changes, small stuff like using a `with` block for your file handle and output formatting, but most of the changes come down to program flow.

Aside from `if/else` statements, the code makes use of intentional infinite loops `while True` that will be "broken out of" (with `break`) when a certain condition is met.  This is similar to the `do/while` construct in other languages.

The idea is that the user enters a time, which you only care about if the speed you calculate from it it exceeds the speed limit.

If it doesn't, you just ask another time.

It it does, *only then* do you care about the license plate number.  So then is when you ask it.  You force the user to enter a valid license plate -- invalid ones (ones that fail the regex match) display an error and the program instructs the user to try again.

Once the user has entered a matching plate number, it's appended to the `over_limit` list (which you don't do anything with, by the way) and written to the file.  Note that the file is being opened in `'w'` mode instead of `a` mode, so each time you run the program, the output file will be "emptied".

To gracefully exit, when you're asked for a time, you can type 'x' and the program says "Goodbye" and terminates.

Note that from your comments since I started writing, it looks like you'll need to update the `PLATE_PATTERN` expression.